# Nuxt js static pages relative URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on some static pages using Nuxt.js (MPA). Whenever I run the `generate` command, all `<nuxt-link>` URLs start from root, i.e `/`. For example, my structure is:

```
pages
    |
     - index.vue
     - policy.vue
```

And in `index.vue` I have linked policy page as:

```
<nuxt-link to="policy.html"> Policy </nuxt-link>
```

which results in `/policy.html` instead of `policy.html`.

Comment: Link to a file, regardless if it is root relative (`/policy.html`) or relative (`policy.html`) is not a valid prop for `nuxt-link` component, which is an alias for `router-link`. Instead, a path (without extension) or route name should be passed. See more in `router-link` [API reference](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `policy.html` by a path so like this

Wrong :
`<nuxt-link to="policy.html"> Policy </nuxt-link>`

Right :
`<nuxt-link to="/policy"> Policy </nuxt-link>`

Check the docs for more informations [Nuxt Link](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/)

Comment: In both cases (wrong/right) it would take path from root. i.e.` xyz.com/policy/` and would fail if site is hosted on `xyz.com/test/`

Comment: If you want a custom url like this you need to specify the root in the nuxt.config.js like this `export default {
  router: {
    base: '/test/'
  }
}` More infos : here https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/